# ECMAscript 6 code not working

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm new here.

I'm reading a book called ' Learning Javascript , 3rd edition ' and one of the exercises was running this code:  :

```
"use strict";



let sentences = [
{ subject: 'JavaScript', verb: 'is', object: 'great' },
{ subject: 'Elephants', verb: 'are', object: 'large' },
];
function say( {subject, verb, object} ) {
console.log(`${subject} ${verb} ${object}`);
}
for(let s of sentences) {
say(s);
}
```

But this error appears.

```
SyntaxError : Unexpected token {
```

what is wrong with the code?

I'm using node.js, gulp.js and babel to transpiling for a es5 code.

P.S: Sorry for my bad english, i'm still learning and i'm trying not use the Google Tranlate

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `function say( {subject, verb, object} )` is the issue. You don't put `{}` around function arguments. It should be `function say( subject, verb, object )`.

Comment: @Mjh This is destructuring. The problem is the transpiler doesn't handle it everywhere. OP, the problem is in HOW you transpile. What preset do you use ?

Comment: If it's destructuring shouldn't `{subject, verb, object}` be `{subject:subject, verb:verb, object:object}`? Based on the examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment, I've never used it myself.

Comment: @MattMcCabe No, this is the correct syntax (the long one is also valid, of course). But we can't answer the question as is, the problem is in the call to babel and it isn't described. OP, the answer is probably you don't pass the preset to babel (see https://github.com/babel/babelify)

Comment: Yes, this is a destructuring object. i'm tryin search about this in google, but I do not find anything to help me.

Comment: I'm new in babel, node, grunt... you could help me find a solution for this?

Comment: @DenysSéguret - thanks, I knew it's probably something that I've no clue about so I made a comment instead of the answer :)

Comment: @EduardoB. Assuming you use babelify (this is the best solution in gulp), try doing `npm install --save-dev babel-preset-es2015 babel-preset-stage-0`

Comment: Hum... the question mentions gulp and a comment mentions grunt... ?

Comment: Still giving the same error. I install babelify and the babel-presets,but when i tryin run the code the error appears. How I use the babelify?

Comment: @DenysSéguret: I don't think `babel-preset-stage-0` is needed (and I think it should not be used unless you need it, there's a reason it's not the default)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

My gulp file was wrong, and I install the preset of 2015.

It is my gulp file now

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');


gulp.task('default', () => {
return gulp.src("es6/**/*.js")
.pipe(babel({presets:["es2015"]}))
.pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
});
```

Thanks for the peoples who helped me